# How to keep guides in illustrator below objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

I am using isometric guides in Illustrator and cant seem to keep the guides from showing through the objects with a solid fill.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. That's the way guides are supposed to work. They'd be pretty useless as guides if this were not the case. Not sure if there is a real problem here. Guides are not visible when exporting or outputting finished artwork. You can also toggle guide visibility on/off using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+;

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change the menu to always lock the guides. (This used to be the default).

[image]

Choose `View > Guides > Lock Guides`, then any guide you create or drag from a ruler will *automatically* be locked when you let go of it. If you wish to reverse this setting, merely choose it again from the menu. It's a "sticky* setting. It'll remain on whatever you set it to.

---

Another option is to use **Layers**. Guides are just special objects, they reside on the layer they were created on...

[image]

I will often create a "guide layer" and whenever I need a new guide I highlight that layer in the **Layers Panel** before creating the guide. I can keep this layer below (or above) any other layer I need.

The *problem* with the layer method is if you lock the *layer* it's not going to lock the actual guides. The layer can be locked and the guides will still be selectable and movable if they aren't locked via the menu item. Guide locking is *only* controlled by the menu item. But, the layer method does allow you to control stacking order of the guides within the overall layer stack.

And Guides *are* objects, so you can always expand a layer and move a guide in the object stack

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I made a new grid and did not make it into a guide. This caused the lines to stay behind the objects.